# Chaining multiple asynchronous functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await

```
class Calc {
  constructor(num) {
    this.num = num;
  }

  add() {
    // code
  }

  subtract() {
    // code
  }

  multiply() {
    // code
  }

  divide() {
    // code
  }
}

const getRes = async () => {
  const res = await new Calc(10)
    .add(30)
    .subtract(5)
    .multiply(2);

    console.log(res) //prints the result
};

getRes();
```

How do i achieve this behaviour? I want to be able to chain all the methods (which in this example are add, subtract, multiply, divide) one after another and when i **await** them it should return the result same as when we **await** mongoose queries.

I know ordinary calculation isn't asynchronous, but imagine that the methods *were* asynchronous - what would the proper code to achieve the desired effect look like?

Comment: why do you need to `await`. are those function asynchronous?

Comment: @hussain.codes Yes, actually i'm trying to figure out how does mongoose chain its query functions (like sort, limit, select etc...). So let's assume that all of these functions are asynchronous and now how do i chain them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return an object which has the `add`, `subtract`, etc methods on it. When those methods are invoked, reassign an internal property of the instance, which holds the Promise. At the end of the chain, access that Promise property on the instance:

```js
class Calc {
  constructor(num) {
    this.prom = Promise.resolve(num);
  }

  add(arg) {
    this.prom = this.prom.then(res => res + arg);
    return this;
  }

  subtract(arg) {
    this.prom = this.prom.then(res => res - arg);
    return this;
  }

  multiply(arg) {
    this.prom = this.prom.then(res => res * arg);
    return this;
  }
}

const getRes = async () => {
  const res = await new Calc(10)
    .add(30)
    .subtract(5)
    .multiply(2)
    .prom;

    console.log(res) //prints the result
};

getRes();
```